# Protobuf Linker Error

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to create an executable from object files. 
Here are the commands that I have used -

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++0x -march=native -fopenmp -pthread -I/usr/local/include -DUSESSE -DUSEOMP -c -o timer.o timer.cpp
g++  model.pb.cc -Wall -O3 -std=c++0x -march=native -fopenmp -pthread -I/usr/local/include -DUSESSE -DUSEOMP  `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf` -c -o ffm-model.o
g++ -c ffm.cpp -Wall -O3 -std=c++0x -march=native -fopenmp -pthread -I/usr/local/include -DUSESSE -DUSEOMP -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -lpthread -I. -o ffm.o 
g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++0x -march=native -fopenmp -pthread -I/usr/local/include -DUSESSE -DUSEOMP -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -lpthread -o ffm-train ffm-train.cpp ffm.o timer.o ffm-model.o
```

But I am getting errors -

> ffm.o: In function `ffm::ffm_save_model(ffm::ffm_model&,
>   std::string)': ffm.cpp:(.text+0x38b9): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::Message::SerializeToOstream(std::ostream*) const'
>   ffm.o: In function
>   `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>::Reserve(int)':
>   ffm.cpp:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf13RepeatedFieldIiE7ReserveEi[_ZN6google8protobuf13RepeatedFieldIiE7ReserveEi]+0x67):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAligned(unsigned
>   long)'
>   ffm.cpp:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf13RepeatedFieldIiE7ReserveEi[_ZN6google8protobuf13RepeatedFieldIiE7ReserveEi]+0xfa):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::Arena::OnArenaAllocation(std::type_info const*,
>   unsigned long) const' ffm-model.o: In function`
>   protobuf_model_2eproto::InitDefaultsFFMmodelImpl()':
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int, int, char const*)'
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::InitProtobufDefaults()'
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::OnShutdownDestroyMessage(void const*)'
>   ffm-model.o: In function`
>   protobuf_model_2eproto::protobuf_AssignDescriptors()':
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(std::string const&,
>   google::protobuf::internal::MigrationSchema const*,
>   google::protobuf::Message const* const*, unsigned int const*, 
>   google::protobuf::MessageFactory*, google::protobuf::Metadata*,
>   google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const**,
>   google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor const**)' ffm-model.o: In function`
>   protobuf_model_2eproto::protobuf_RegisterTypes(std::string const&)':
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::RegisterAllTypes(google::protobuf::Metadata
>   const*, int)' ffm-model.o: In function`
>   protobuf_model_2eproto::AddDescriptorsImpl()':
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void
>   const*, int)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char
>   const*, void (*)(std::string const&))' ffm-model.o: In function
>   `FFMmodel::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)':
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x7a6): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadTagFallback(unsigned
>   int)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0x9db): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SkipField(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*,
>   unsigned int, google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet*)' ffm-model.o: In
>   function`
>   FFMmodel::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)
>   const': model.pb.cc:(.text+0xa40): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteInt32(int, int,
>   google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0xa71):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteInt32(int, int,
>   google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0xaa2):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteInt32(int, int,
>   google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0xad1):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBool(int, bool,
>   google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0xc02):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SerializeUnknownFields(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet
>   const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' ffm-model.o: In
>   function`FFMmodel::InternalSerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(bool,
>   unsigned char*) const': model.pb.cc:(.text+0xe01): undefined reference
>   to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet
>   const&, unsigned char*)' ffm-model.o: In function`
>   FFMmodel::ByteSizeLong() const': model.pb.cc:(.text+0xec5): undefined
>   reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::ComputeUnknownFieldsSize(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet
>   const&)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0xed9): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Int32Size(google::protobuf::RepeatedField
>   const&)' ffm-model.o: In function
>   `FFMmodel::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::Message const&)':
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x101f): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel,
>   char const*, int)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0x1035): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const*)'
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x104d): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage&)'
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x1061): undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
>   model.pb.cc:(.text+0x108e): undefined reference to`
>   google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Merge(google::protobuf::Message
>   const&, google::protobuf::Message*)' model.pb.cc:(.text+0x10bc):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Your linkage consumes libraries before the object files that refer to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305704/1362568)